# Issues with jQuery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, hyperlink, twitter-bootstrap-3

So far, I've created a function that has a counter that accumulates whenever "Link" is clicked on and resets whenever you click outside of "Link". When the counter==2, you are redirected to the link's page and the counter resets. It's probably a silly mistake or something because I'm new to jQuery but for some reason my counter never resets, so when you click on the link, then outside of it, then back on it, you are redirected, which shouldn't happen. [Here's my Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/PRTKsAyojJ).

HTML:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container">

                <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">

                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">                            
                        <li class="dropdown">   
                            <a href="page.html" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span>Link</span><b class="caret"></b></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
                            </ul><!-- END: "dropdown-menu" -->      
                        </li><!-- END: "dropdown" -->

                    </ul><!-- END: "collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse" -->
                </div><!-- END: "container" -->
            </div><!-- END: "container" -->
        </div><!-- END: "navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" -->
```

jQuery:

```
 $(document).on("click", "span", function() {
    if(typeof $(this).data('clicks') == 'undefined') {
        $(this).data('clicks', 1);
    } else {
        $(this).data('clicks', $(this).data('clicks')+1);
    }
    if ($(this).data('clicks')==2){
            $(this).data('clicks', 0); 
            $(this).window.open("page.html");
    }
});

$(document).click(function(event) {     
    if(!$(event.target).closest("span").length) {   
        $(this).data('clicks', 0);
    }     
});
```

Suggestions?

EDIT: Using the suggestions, below, it works *almost* perfectly. It seems that clicking slightly below "Link," enabling the menu to drop, then clicking on "Link" results in moments where that second click doesn't register, thus you aren't redirected. Is there a way to fix this minor bug? It must have something to do with the target of the event.

EDIT #2: I managed to get it to work by adding (poor markup, ik):

```
if (counter==1 && $('.dropdown-menu').is(":visible")) {
    window.open("accomplishments.html");
    resetCounter();
}
```

right above

```
if (shouldOpen()) {
    window.open("accomplishments.html");
    resetCounter();
}
```

Comment: You're missing the closing `});` at the end of the second `click` event handler function. Also, are you sure you should be doing `$(this).window.open("page.html");` I don't think a span or the jQuery superset object its contained in has a `window` property. I believe a simple `window.open("page.html");` will do to open a popup containing "page.html".

Comment: Thank you, even with those brackets, it doesn't work however. EDIT: the window.open function is fine, it works on its own. I think my problem has to do with the variable "clicks," as the functions don't seem to be communicating properly.

Comment: Did you try changing `$(this).window.open("page.html");` to `window.open("page.html");`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's 2 problems:

1: You're not cancelling the default action when the span inside the link is clicked (which is to go to that link). You can do this by accepting a parameter in your callback `e` which is the event that has occurred and calling the `preventDefault()` method on it.

2: You're resetting the counter on `this` not the `span`.

Here's the working code:

```
$(document).on("click", "span", function (e) {

     e.preventDefault();

     if (typeof $(this).data('clicks') == 'undefined') {
         $(this).data('clicks', 1);
     } else {
         $(this).data('clicks', $(this).data('clicks') + 1);
     }
     if ($(this).data('clicks') == 2) {
         $(this).data('clicks', 0);
         window.open("page.html");
     }

     console.log($(this).data('clicks'));
 });

 $(document).click(function (event) {
     if (!$(event.target).closest("span").length) {
         $('span').data('clicks', 0);
     }
 });
```

Here's a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LqrGd/

I would argue that unless you have a very good reason for binding your data to the DOM, don't. The counter could just be a simple JS variable `counter`. Here's another example doing it this way:

http://jsfiddle.net/k8wGW/1/

```
var counter = 0;

$(document).on("click", "span", function (e) {

     e.preventDefault();

    counter++;

     if (counter === 2) {
         window.open("page.html");
         counter = 0;
     }

 });

 $(document).click(function (event) {
     if (!$(event.target).closest("span").length) {
         counter = 0;
     }
 });
```

You could clean this up even more by using functions and constants to express your intent:

http://jsfiddle.net/k8wGW/3/

```
var counter = 0;

const EMPTY_COUNTER = 0, FULL_COUNTER = 2;

var shouldOpen = function () {
    return counter === FULL_COUNTER;
};

var resetCounter = function () {
    counter = EMPTY_COUNTER;
};

var incrementCounter = function () {
    counter++;
};

$(document).on("click", "span", function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    incrementCounter();

    if (shouldOpen()) {
        window.open("page.html");
        resetCounter();
    }

});

$(document).click(function (event) {
    if (!$(event.target).closest("span").length) {
        resetCounter();
    }
});
```

The issue you're having in the EDIT is because it only registers a click on the `span` to increment the counter. As you can see the span is quite small. If you change it to listen on clicks to the whole `a` element, you should get the desired behaviour:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Wow, this is very thorough; thank you, but that minor problem that I mention in my EDIT still remains. It's really weird.

Comment: Ah, wow this is great. Thank you very much, man. Great help. I'm a be referring to your answers quite a bit. Thanks.

Comment: No probs, glad I could help.

Comment: Hey, when you have the time, could you offer a solution to another question I asked? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24767059/problems-when-toggling-a-class-called-aactive-using-jquery?noredirect=1#comment38432704_24767059

Answer (score 1):

That is because you reset on document click is not resetting the data of the `span` like in your other function.

Instead on using `this`, select the `span` :

```
$(document).click(function(event) {     
    if(!$(event.target).closest("span").length) {   
        $('span').data('clicks', 0);
    }
});
```

http://www.bootply.com/VIMoiIbWqC

I'm also not sure about this line : `$(this).window.open("page.html");`

Shouldn't it be `window.open("page.html")`?

Comment: You know, with both of those changes, it's working perfectly fine. Thank you so much. I knew it was something so minor but I couldn't put my finger on it. You made my day.