# Problems when toggling a class called "a:active" using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, toggleclass

As it stands, clicking on "Link" twice redirects you to a page, but whenever you click on and around it such that the menu drops down or goes up, the CSS code

```
a:active span {
    color:#bdbcae;
}
```

is put into effect. What I am trying to do is make it so that the link only changes color when you click it the second time, resulting in you being redirected to the page. If you click it only once so that only the menu drops down, I want the link to remain its default color.

This is the code in my function below that I was looking at to accomplish this

```
 if ($(this).data('clicks')==2){
       $(this).data('clicks', 0); 
       window.open("accomplishments.html");
 }
```

I was thinking of adding something along the lines of `$(this).addClass("active")` within this if statement but that doesn't work - and then making it do `$(this).removeClass("active")` whenever this isn't the case, but none of this works. See my full code below.

**[Here's my Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/q1cCLzo0R7).**

HTML:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
            <div class="container">

                <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>

                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">

                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">                            
                        <li class="dropdown">   
                            <a href="page.html" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span>Link</span><b class="caret"></b></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
                            </ul><!-- END: "dropdown-menu" -->      
                        </li><!-- END: "dropdown" -->

                    </ul><!-- END: "collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse" -->
                </div><!-- END: "container" -->
            </div><!-- END: "container" -->
        </div><!-- END: "navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" -->
```

CSS:

```
a span {
    color:#ffffff;  
}
a:hover *.caret {
    color:#bdbcae;
}
a:active span {
    color:#bdbcae;
}
a:active *.caret {
    color:#bdbcae;
}
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).on("click", "span", function() {
         if(typeof $(this).data('clicks') == 'undefined') {
             $(this).data('clicks', 1);
             }else {
             $(this).data('clicks', $(this).data('clicks')+1);
         }
         if ($(this).data('clicks')==2){
                 $(this).data('clicks', 0); 
                 window.open("page.html");
         }
     });

$(document).click(function(event) {

    if(!$(event.target).closest("span").length) {        
            $("span").data('clicks', 0);  
    }        
});
```

Comment: `addClass` should work. You just need to change the CSS to `a.active` instead of `a:active`.

Comment: I followed your suggestion, but still nothing. Could you look at my [modified code](http://www.bootply.com/bcuXnwD3h4) and see what's going on? Thanks.

Comment: `$(this).window.open()` isn't valid. jQuery objects don't have a `window` property. Use `window.open()`.

Comment: Okay, would you mind looking at it now? http://www.bootply.com/sgwSzegcjY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think using a "click" and a "dblclick" event will help you, why do you want to set a particular color if you're going to redirect user ?

Jquery Double click event : http://api.jquery.com/dblclick/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but double-clicking wouldn't achieve the same results. I want the color to change in order to keep it consistent with the color changes that occur in my other links when the user presses on them before being redirected.