# Selecting class a:active span vs. a.active span in jQuery function?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

In my navbar, I have an element with both a span tag and an < a > tag. However, I'm confused because here's my CSS:

```
a span {
    color:#ffffff;  
}
a:hover *.caret {
    color:#bdbcae;
}
a:active span {
    color:#bdbcae;
}
a:active *.caret {
    color:#bdbcae;
}
```

Now, the way it works is whenever I click in the box surrounding the link, causing the menu to dropdown for instance, the link changes color according to the following CSS:

```
a:active span {
    color:#bdbcae;
}
```

which is great, but I'd also like to toggle this class, but I don't know how. I previously asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24767059/problems-when-toggling-a-class-called-aactive-using-jquery), but nobody gave me a straight answer.

If, say, I want to add or remove this class from the link, how do I do this, i.e., what should my function look like, because I've tried

```
$("span").removeClass("active");
```

but that doesn't do anything because of the "a:active". I'm seriously confused as to how to do this. So, could someone explain to me how to do this?

**[Here's my Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/Hfx6Th6XuD).**

HTML:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">         
        <button class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navHeaderCollapse">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>

        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse">

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">                            
                <li class="dropdown">   
                    <a href="page.html" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span>Link</span><b class="caret"></b></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
                    </ul><!-- END: "dropdown-menu" -->      
                </li><!-- END: "dropdown" -->

            </ul>
            <!-- END: "collapse navbar-collapse navHeaderCollapse" -->
        </div><!-- END: "container" -->
    </div><!-- END: "container" -->
</div><!-- END: "navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" -->
```

Comment: You've got it all wrong, `:active` is not a class, it's simply a CSS [state selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:active), triggered when a link is clicked on. You cannot expect to manipulate it as a class, hell, you can't manipulate it at all. It is never 'set' explicitly in your HTML as `class="active"`, hence why you cannot remove it.

Comment: Shit, lol. Okay, so how could I redefine it in order to be able to toggle it in such a way?

Comment: Just put your styles in a regular class selector (replace the colon in `:active`with a dot) and toggle it with JS/ jQuery. jQuery provides a [`toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) function to do this.

Comment: Should I make it a.active span {
 color:#bdbcae;
} ? or leave out the "a." - I don't understand what the inclusion of "a" does.

Comment: That's up to you, both are fine. It increases specificity and/or code understandability. Eg, if you use the *active* class on other elements you could give them different styling depending on the element (eg links in nav vs. active tabs or w/e).

Comment: The inclusion of the `a` means that the `.active` class will only apply to `<a>` tags. Leaving it off means you can apply it to any element.

Answer (score 1):

In your css, `:active` is not representing a class, it is a state of element.

So, to achieve your requirement, you need to add a class to your `<a>` element and do css corresponding to this class.

```
a.myClass span {
    color:#ffffff;  
}
a.myClass:hover *.caret {
    color:#bdbcae;
}
a:active span {
    color:#bdbcae;
}
a.myClass:active *.caret {
    color:#bdbcae;
}
```

And add `myClass` to your html  element.

```
<a class="myClass"> Test </a>
```

Now you can remove `myClass` using jquery,

```
$("span").removeClass("myClass");
```

Hope this will help you !!!